# Сбиваются настройки в Odoo

Tags: python, python-2.x, settings, odoo

Сделал наследования настроек модуля Sale и добавил туда несколько полей. Но если я обновляю модуль, настройки сбиваются.

```
class RentalConfiguration(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = ['sale.config.settings']

    reserve_days_before = fields.Integer(
        'Reserve Days before event',
        help='Number of days before event when product should be reserved',
    )
    max_rental_days = fields.Integer(
        'Maximum number of rental days', 
    
    )

    count_days_to_start_rental = fields.Integer(
        'Count days to start rental', 
    )

    max_choices_frames = fields.Integer(
        'Maximum choices frames', 
    )
```

Настройки могут также сбиться на следующий день. Если знаете решения прошу подскажите.
Версия ODOO 9

С уважением,
Lairion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы наследуете неправильный класс: TransientModel. Данные обьектов этого класса хранятся временно в базе и регулярно стираются крон джобом от туда. Класс предназначен для специальных случаев, как например визарды.
Для всех остальных случаев применяется стандартный класс models.Model

Comment: Спасибо! Буду знать!